# ArangoDB: How to Export an Arango query result to a CSV file from Arangoshell?

Tags: export-to-csv, arangodb

I would like to export the result of this query into a CSV file. Provided how to export this query from Arango shell?

Below is the query.

```
let lstofnodes=(for doc in Account  
    filter doc.fraud == true
        for v in 1..3 outbound doc graph "G1"
            return distinct v._id)
for d in Transaction
  filter d._from IN lstofnodes AND d._to IN lstofnodes 
  return distinct {"from":d._from, "to":d._to, "Amount": d.Amount, "TIme": d.Time}
```

Comment: This question and it's answers should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370162/converting-json-to-csv-in-javascript

Comment: I did not understand it, could you  please explain it.

Comment: This is an Arango shell query and I would like to export the result of this query into a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer in the post I mentioned in my comment ([Converting Json to CSV in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370162/converting-json-to-csv-in-javascript)) is completely usable in arangosh, you do program javascript in the shell after all.

Here is a console transcript of an example session using the technique:

Prepare db and aql modules:

```js
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> var db = require("@arangodb").db

127.0.0.1:8529@_system> var aql = require("@arangodb").aql;
```

`seperator` could be `\t`, but we use a comma

```js
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> const seperator = ',';
```

`headers` contains the names of the fields/properties of the documents we want to write to the csv file.  They are used as column headers as well

```js
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> let headers = ['prop1', 'prop2'];
```

The simple example collection I created for this example only contains two documents, so I don't filter anything - the `.toArray()` call is important here, the `map` call is otherwise not possible.  This can bite you, if the amount of data you need to extract does not fit into the available memory.

```js
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> var data = db._query(
    aql`FOR doc IN test RETURN doc`
 ).toArray();
```

This creates an array of strings.  The first is the column header line, then follows the map call that extracts the properties from the documents and creates a csv string for each.  If a field value can contain a comma, you would use enclosing quotes here, you would have to escape quote characters in values then

```js
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> const csv = [
    headers.join(seperator),
    ...data.map(
           row => headers.map( 
               field => `${row[field]}`
           ).join(seperator)
    )
];
```

Finally we join the lines into one string seperated by newlines

```js
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> csv.join("\n");
prop1,prop2
val,other
foo,baz
```

To write the javascript to a file:

```js
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> var fs = require("fs");

127.0.0.1:8529@_system> fs.write("mydata.csv", csv.join("\n"));
true
```

Comment: arangoexport \--type csv \--fields title,category1,category2 \--custom-query "FOR a in Account return a }"

Comment: This was the query that was given in the documentation and it does not seem to be working as it returns an syntax error in the arangoexport itself.

Comment: What I posted is an actual transcript, so that works and would produce csv for you, if your query would work.  The small error snippet above looks like a syntax error somewhere, yes, but it is not conclusive - this would be a new question with as much information as possible.

Comment: I executed the script that you had shared and was getting the following error which states permission denied  cannot write file.

Comment: `fs.write` in this case writes to the working directory of the arangosh process, you have to have write permission there.